# How should I implement items that are normalized in the database in object oriented design?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

How should I implement items that are normalized in the database in object oriented classes? In the database I have a table of items and `Groups`. Each item belongs to one group:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Inventory                              |
+----+------+-------+----------+---------+
| Id | Name | Price | Quantity | GroupId |
+----+------+-------+----------+---------+
| 43 | Box  | 34.00 |     456  |     4   |
| 56 | Ball | 56.50 |       3  |     6   |
| 66 | Tin  | 23.00 |      14  |     4   |
+----+------+-------+----------+---------+
Totally 3000 lines

+----------------------+
| Groups               |
+---------+------+-----+
| GroupId | Name | VAT |
+---------+------+-----+
|     4   | Mini | 0.2 |
|     6   | Big  | 0.3 |
+---------+------+-----+
Totally 10 lines
```

I will use the OOP classes in a GUI where the user can edit items and groups in the inventory. It should also be easy to do calculations with a bunch of items. Group information like VAT is needed for calculations.

I will write an `Item` class, but do I need a `Group` class? If so, should I keep them in a global location or how do I access them when I need it for item calculations? Is there any design pattern for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the most common *practice* is to use an ORM (object-relational mapping) tool. These are available to most any modern OO language, and they take care of generating the classes needed to interact with the database, managing retrieval and updating, and managing connection lifetime.

That aside, yes, you need a `Group` class that has a collection of `Item`s, and (ideally) a reference from `Item` to its parent `Group`. This is one of the areas where an ORM can help, since it can ensure that these two references (the collection of children and the parent reference) stay in sync.

Comment: But if I keep all `Item` **in** a `Group` class, then I have to have all my `Item`s in memory? That sounds tricky, because I don't need all the 3000 items at the same time. Or maybe that is the best solution anyway.. have to think about it, thanks.

Comment: There's no way to model this with groups without keeping all of a particular group's items in memory (or, at least, something that represents the item, if not the item itself). Don't optimize prematurely; 3000 instances is not unreasonable.

Comment: You can just keep the IDs in the list and lazy load them as needed if memory is a real issue.  ORM tools have sorted this out better than you will.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a Group class.  It looks like it has a 1:many relationship with Inventory, where Group is the parent.  Group will have a reference to a collection or set of Inventory.

Comment: The `Group` has a 1:M relationship with `Item`, many items can be in the same group.